# Comparing String Structure

Tags: string, algorithm, f#

I'm working on a project in F# in which I am hoping to come up with a way to identify whether or not two strings have the same structure. I know that there are algorithms out there (like Levenshtein Distance) that provide an approximation of how similar strings are content-wise, but I am more interested in comparing the actual structure of the string. In terms of structure vs. content, consider the following example:

"07/14/2015" and "11/06/1999" would be classified as very different according to an algorithm like Levenshtein Distance. However, they are both structurally the same (dates).

Additionally, a group of strings that all begin with three letters ("USA123", "USA456", "USA789") would ideally be recognized to have a different structure as other six character strings such as "123123" or "USAUSA".

I realize that this would most likely be a fairly complicated solution, but I was wondering if anything like this exists and I missed it, or if anyone has any thoughts/ideas regarding the matter.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like an AI problem rather than an algorithmic question. Certainly not a language question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question looks a bit subjective as it invites for opinion-based answers, many of which may be equally good. Let me try answering, but again, it may or may not be good for your particular purposes.

If your application is just a small project intended for self-education then a series of simple Regular Expressions may be fine, provided that you merge them into a series of attempts.

If the project is large and supposed to grow somehow (e.g., new string formats may arise) then I would recommend some **parser combinator library**, like [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/) which is great for parsing complex strings. There's also a [fparsec](/questions/tagged/fparsec) tag here.

With a combinator, you may develop your individual parsers and combine them in however is needed, like this:

```
// Domain specifics
type MyData =
    | Date of DateTime
    | CountryCode of (string * code)
    | Error

// Parsers
let parseDate: Parser<MyData> =
    ... // something returning MyData.Date(x)
let parseCountryCode: Parser<MyData> =
    ... // something returning MyData.CountryCode(x, y)

// a simple combined parser
let parseRoot: Parser<MyData> =
    [parseDate; parseCountryCode; parseSomethingElse;]
    |> choice

let myCode stringTroParse =
    let foundValue =
        match runParserOnString parseRoot myUserState myStreamName stringTroParse with
        | Success(result, _, _) -> result
        | Failure(_, _, _)      -> MyData.Error
    // here you can work with foundValue as usual
```

Using this approach, comparing structures of several strings becomes trivial: they are parsed into different cases of `MyData` discriminated union.

If occasionally a new parser is needed, you may add another function at the top and add its reference into `parseRoot` body. Also, if something more complicated is needed (e.g. a you need some guard rules or a different way of combining the parsers), the library lets you do that.

Answer (score 1):

Though not a full answer, you could do some very basic tests that will catch the examples you gave above:

1. Prepare a list of types of characters. By this I mean to separate between upper case, lower case, digits, delimiters etc.
2. When comparing two strings, check that the characters in the same place belong to the same group. This will give you the `19/07/1983` and `25/12/1853` are similar, but `19/07/1983` and `25/12/185A` are not. Same with `USAUSA` and `USA123`.

Making the identification more exact is a matter of creating more and more exact groups...

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, you need to classify your characters. After that's done, comparing two sets of character classifications is easy. Here is an F# sample:

```
let areStructurallyEqual (a, b) = 
    let charClass= function 
        | c when Char.IsLetter(c) -> 'L'
        | c when Char.IsDigit(c) -> 'D'
        | c when Char.IsSymbol(c) -> 'S'
        | c when Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) -> ' '
        | _ -> '_'

    let structureString i = new String (i |> Seq.map charClass |> Seq.toArray)
    structureString a = structureString b

[( "07/14/2015", "11/06/1999" ); ("USA123", "USA456"); ("123123", "USA123");]
    |> Seq.map areStructurallyEqual

// returns [ True; True; False; ]
```